# Unicode char from input does not show

Tags: input, unicode, printing, emoji

I am trying to display unicode char based on a user input. If I try to print it in the console.

```
const emoji  = `{\\u${this.state.textInput}}`;
            console.log(emoji);
            console.log(`\u{1f40e}`)
```

But the result is
[image]

Where the first is from the input the second is when the unicode is directly written. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
const emoji = String.fromCodePoint(`0x${this.state.textInput}`);
```

If you escape the whole string with `\\u` then you get a string starting with `\u` instead of a Unicode character that needs to be escaped.